# Algorithm to determine best allocation of funds

Tags: algorithm

So I have a real world situation I'm trying to find a solution for. I'll slightly abstract and tweak the specifics for simplicity.

I have a certain amount of money that I could contribute to one or more buckets. These buckets contain money contributed by 0 or more other people. There is a certain dividend which will be equally split amongst all the buckets, irrespective of how much money is in each bucket. The percentage of the dividend I would receive is based on the percentage of my holdings in a particular bucket relative to the total holdings in that bucket.

How can I figure out the best allocation of my funds across the different buckets to maximize my yield?

For example:

- I have $100 to invest.
- The total dividend is $100.
- There are 3 buckets already containing the following funds.
  --- bucket A: $100
  --- bucket B: $200
  --- bucket C: $300

So one approach is I could put the entire $100 in bucket A. I would have 50% share of that bucket and would therefore get $16.66 of the dividend ((100 / 3) * .5).

I don't think the solution is as simple as finding the single bucket where I'd have the highest percentage. For example, if the buckets were as follows:

--- bucket A: $33.33
--- bucket B: $33.33
--- bucket C: $33.33

I'd be better off splitting my money equally across all 3 buckets and collecting $16.66 from each bucket.

Anyhow, looking for an algorithm to determine the ideal allocation.

Not sure what to try. The only thing I could really think of is brute-forcing by enumerating every possible combination of 0-100 for each bucket, but that very quickly gets nasty in terms of performance.

(FWIW, this is not a homework assignment or coding challenge - real life scenario of something I'm working on)

Comment: that sounds like a variant on the knapsack problem

Comment: hmm.. unrelated to this I actually stumbled upon that a few weeks back. I thought this was different enough, but maybe I'll review that and see if it applies.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you want to add to the lowest bucket until it matches the second lowest.  Add to the lowest 2 until they match the third.  Then add to the lowest 3, and so on.  That means that each dollar is going into the best investments.

The question boils down to figuring out how many you're going to be increasing to level, and then how much more you're going to put into each.

Let's suppose that the buckets start with `buckets = [400, 800, 100, 200]` and you have `1100` to invest.

First we sort by amount `buckets = sorted[buckets]` to get `[100, 200, 400, 800]`.

Next we look at the pairwise differences.  `[200-100, 400-200, 800-400] = [100, 200, 400]`.  That represents how much we have to increase the buckets by.

Now we multiply each pairwise difference by how many buckets we are filling at that point to get the dollar value to reach those thresholds.  `[100*1, 200*2, 400*3] = [100, 400, 1200]`.

Next up we walk the buckets to figure out how many we fill, and how much money we used.

```
start with 1100
bucket 1 cost us 100, 1000 left.
buckets 1,2 cost us 400, 600 left.
buckets 1,2,3 would cost us 1200 so we divide our remaining 600 3 ways for 200 in each.
```

Walking that calculation backwards we added `200` to the `400` bucket, `400` to the `200` bucket, and `500` to the `100` bucket.  For a total of `1100` spent.

Now you just have to code it. :-)

Comment: Unless I did the math wrong, you would be better off adding 250 to 100, 300 to 200, 325 to 400 and 225 to 800.

Comment: @user3386109 You're right.  I was only focused on the returns for the dollar added, and not the losses for the dollars already spent.

Comment: @user3386109 I would honestly just throw it into https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead